# how to only allow one argument at a time

Tags: java, loops

I am allowing the user to enter numbers via command line. I would like to make it so when the user enters more then one number on the command line at a time it displays a message asking for one number then press enter. then carries on.

here is my code. If someone could show me how to implement this I would appreciate it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class programTwo
{   
    private static Double calculate_average( ArrayList<Double> myArr )
    {
        Double sum = 0.0;
        for (Double number: myArr)
        {
            sum += number;
        }
        return sum/myArr.size(); // added return statement
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> myArr = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter a number to be averaged, repeat up to 20 times:");
        String inputs = scan.nextLine();

        while (!inputs.matches("[qQ]") )
        {
            if (count == 20)
            {
                System.out.println("You entered more than 20 numbers, you suck!");
                break;
            }

            Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(inputs); // create a new scanner out of our single line of input
            try{
                myArr.add(scan2.nextDouble());
                count += 1;
                System.out.println("Please enter another number or press Q for your average");
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Stop it swine! Numbers only! Now you have to start over...");
                main(args);
                return;
            }      

            inputs = scan.nextLine();
        }
        Double average = calculate_average(myArr);
        System.out.println("Your average is: " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just not scan the line you read for numbers, but simply parse the whole line as a number (`Double.valueOf(line)`). If the line contains a space, it's no valid number and an Exception will be thrown.

Comment: Is there a way to do it while still using the scanner?

Comment: What's the point in scanning a line for multipe numbers if you only want one per line?

Comment: the assignment was to do it the way it is kinda. I finished the assignment way early and so I have been adding a bunch of extra stuff to further understand the program. we have not learned most of whats in this program I have just managed to put it together. So I am trying to understand how to add something like the ability to only allow one number per line in this current situation.

Comment: That deosn't really make too much sense to me. Scanner, when working on a string, is basically a wrapper for the exact thing I suggested, only it splits the input at whitespace to be able to read more than one Number. But as this is exactly what you do NOT want - why insist on using it? I'm only talking about `scan2`, the other scanner is fine.

Comment: Would you mind illustrating your solution for me so I can understand what your talking about.

Comment: Sure, just give me som time. I'm not able to test it and haven'T doen Java for quite some time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments to the question: Just do not scan the line you read for numbers, but parse it as a single number instead using [`Double.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) (I also beautified the rest of your code a little, see comments in there)

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner           scan  = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Double> myArr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int               count = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a number to be averaged, repeat up to 20 times:");

    // we can use a for loop here to break on q and read the next line instead of that while you had here.
    for (String inputs = scan.nextLine() ; !inputs.matches("[qQ]")  ; inputs = scan.nextLine())
    {
        if (count == 20)
        {
            System.out.println("You entered more than 20 numbers, you suck!");
            break;
        }
        try{
            myArr.add(Double.valueOf(inputs));
            count++; //that'S even shorter than count += 1, and does the exact same thing.
            System.out.println("Please enter another number or press Q for your average");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("You entered more than one number, or not a valid number at all.");
            continue; // Skipping the input and carrying on, instead of just starting over. 
                      // If that's not what you want, just stay with what you had here
        }      

    }
    Double average = calculate_average(myArr);
    System.out.println("Your average is: " + average);
}
```

(Code untested, so there may be errors in there. Please notify me if you got one ;))

Comment: awesome. thanks I was assuming cleaning up my loop was the key to this being a lot cleaner. I have one error here myArr.add(Double.valueOf(line)); the word line is throwing error

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks a ton. Its funny cause after all I have gone through to get where I was I swear your code would of made much more sense it I would of just saw it in the first place. Then again I did learn a lot of things that I would not know... Thanks again!

Comment: NP, that'S what we're all here for after all :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] numbers = inputs.split(" ");
if(numbers.length != 1){
    System.out.println("Please enter only one number");
}
```

Comment: How would I incorporate that in to my code? Do I have to reconstruct my loop so it will jump back in if more than one number is entered?

Comment: Doing `if (inputs.contains(" "))`is more efficient in that case, if we don'T need the two parts anyway